# Can I be Wile E. Coyote, covering my tracks in bear traps?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, actions, traps

I play a fighter who has the feat Quick Draw. After making the Str check to set a bear trap, there's no limit to the length of time the bear trap remains set. Dropping an item is a free action. Could my fighter dump, like, a dozen already-set bear traps from his inventory in one round using only a free action for each bear trap?

Comment: I'm super curious as to how the fighter is carrying around 12 primed bear traps but hasn't managed to accidentally set them off when shoving them into his pack.

Comment: @Cthos He doesn't; all he needs to do is make a successful strength check in between quick drawing the trap and dropping it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No

Much to sorrow of those aspiring to cartoon coyotehood, the feat [Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat---final) is disappointingly specific:

> You can draw a weapon as a free action instead of as a move action. You can draw a hidden weapon (see the Sleight of Hand skill) as a move action.
>
> A character who has selected this feat may throw weapons at his full normal rate of attacks (much like a character with a bow).
>
> Alchemical items, potions, scrolls, and wands cannot be drawn quickly using this feat.

Assuming a house rule hasn't added to [Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) the [bear trap](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps/bear-traps-cr-1), it typically takes a move action that provokes an attack of opportunity to [retrieve a stored item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat) such as a bear trap, which usually limits a creature to dropping, during its turn, any number bear traps held in hand plus two.

To overcome this unfortunate limitation on the feat Quick Draw, take the third-party feat [Organized Inventory](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/kobold-press/general-feats---3rd-party---kobold-press/organized-inventory).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, but you should ask your DM.

> Free actions don't take any time at all, **though there may be limits to
>   the number of free actions you can perform in a turn**. Free actions
>   rarely incur attacks of opportunity. Some common free actions are
>   described below.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Free-Actions